# Is there any way I can specify the platform for os.path?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am under Windows, but I need to process some unix-style path, such as:

```
In[4]: os.path.abspath('/prj/vl')
Out[4]: 'C:\\prj\\vl'
```

which is not the correct output I want. So I am wondering if there is a way that I can force `os.path` to work as it is under Unix? I.e. I want to see if there is anything similar to: `os.path.setos('Linux')`

Comment: Try `os.path.abspath('prj/vl')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.path` is a different module depending on your OS. As [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) in the `os.path` documentation, you can explicitly import the version for Unix-style paths:

```
import posixpath
```

The other versions are `ntpath` for Windows paths, `macpath` for old-style MacOS paths, and `os2emxpath` for OS/2 EMX paths.

Answer (score 2):

Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in python standard library. The `os.path` module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats. They all have the same interface:

```
`posixpath` for UNIX-style paths
`ntpath` for Windows paths
`macpath` for old-style MacOS paths
`os2emxpath` for OS/2 EMX paths
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: This answer is 1:1 copied from https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html, I think it should be quoted

Answer (score 1):

You can use `posixpath` instead of `os.path` - actually, `os.path` uses either `posixpath` or `ntpath` depending on the system.